# Square Root of Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, self-learning

> **Question**: Suppose that $\displaystyle \frac{2}{\theta_0}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\sim\displaystyle\chi_{2n}^2$ and $\displaystyle 2\theta_0\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\sim\displaystyle\chi_{2n}^2$. And these two are independent. That is, $x_i'$s are independent with each other; $y_i'$s are independent with each other; and $x_i'$s and $y_i'$s are independent with each other.  What is the distribution of $\displaystyle \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\sum_{i=1}^n y_i}$?

I don't know what knowledge on probability this question refers to. However, it only seems natural to say that $\displaystyle \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\sum_{i=1}^n y_i}\sim\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}\left(\chi_{2n}^2\right)^2}\sim\frac{1}{2}\chi_{2n}^2$. Is this right, please? Can people do this, please? Thank you!

There was a bit of discussion on notation matter. So I made it more conventional. Now could anyone suggest something about the real issue here, please? Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by $\frac{\theta_0}{2} \chi_{2n}^2$.  That's not a distribution.  Either $\frac{2}{\theta_0} \sum y_i \sim \chi_{2n}^2$, or $\sum y_i \sim \chi_{2n}^2$.

Comment: are $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i$ independent?

Comment: @alexjo Sorry I forgot to state that. Yes, they are. Please see the update.

Comment: @heropup $\frac{\theta_0}{2}$ is simply a constant.

Comment: It **still** does not make sense.  We do not say, for example, that $X \sim 2 {\rm Binomial}(n, p)$.  What does it even mean to say that a random variable is some constant times a distribution?  This is sloppy:  we must ALWAYS write $f(X) \sim {\rm Binomial}(n,p)$, or something to that effect:  a *function* of a random variable follows a distribution, rather than a distribution is multiplied by some constant.

Comment: $X\sim a\chi^2$ usually means $a^{-1}X\sim \chi^2$.

Comment: @StefanHansen ...And such notations, while natural in informal discussions between experts, should be avoided in any teaching context.

Comment: @heropup Stefan's explanation is right. Besides, that is not the point of the question. It is simply a matter of notation anyway.

Comment: Then you should have written it as such.  And it is very much the point, because confusing notation prevents people from answering your question, and reflects a lack of understanding.  Go back and read my first comment:  I even tried to interpret what you meant and **ASKED** you if that was what you meant, and you did not say so.  So, what am I supposed to think?

Comment: @heropup Thanks for pointing that out. I have revised the notation.

Answer (score 1):

The density is proportional to 
$$x^nA(x^2)\mathbf 1_{x\geqslant0},
$$ where, for every $t\geqslant0$, 
$$A(t)=\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-u-t/u}\mathrm du.
$$
Thus, $A(t)$ is in $(0,1)$ for every $t\geqslant0$, $A(0)=+1$, $A(+\infty)=0$, $A$ is convex and nonincreasing and $A$ solves the differential equation $tA''(t)-A(t)=0$.